# How do you detect XButton1 pressed with focusing any window?

Tags: c#, wndproc

I want to make a background program that overrides my mouse button to do something I want(The concept is same as global hotkey). Especially when XButton1 (back button on the mouse) is pressed, I want to do some kind of macro work.

I have tried many ways and made it work if the form is clicked with following codes,

```
Protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
   if (m.Msg == Hotkeys.Constants.MK_XBUTTONDOWN) // Hotkeys.Constants.MK_XBUTTONDOWN == 0x020B;
   { 
        // Do something
   }
}
```

## I have got the number 0x020B from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-xbuttondown

Folowing codes are what I did to make global hotkeys, but couldn't figure out how to make global mouse click,

```
if (m.Msg == Hotkeys.Constants.WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID) //WM_HOTKEY_MSG_ID = 0x0312
{
    int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();
    if (GetActiveWindowTitle() == "I want to make global hotkeys to do certain work at this program name")
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Can I get at least some key words for overriding my XButton1 or XButton2?

Comment: its not clear what your question is,

Comment: @hessamhedieh Sorry for unclear question, I just want to make a program that overrides XButton1 (usually button that's on the side of a mouse).